# Manipulate specific regions of matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to make a manipulate a matrix/look-up table in matlab. Here is the Matrix I am working with:

```
0   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50

0   3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
20  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
27  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
34  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
41  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
49  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
56  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
63  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
71  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
78  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
85  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
93  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
100  3   4   5   6   4   5   5   5   5   5
```

The First column and row i want to use as my variables. So for instance if i want to manipulate a certain region, how would I do so? e.g. all values between 5 - 15 (top row) and 20-41 (first column) were to be multiplied by 1.33.

Ideally, i want this to be used in a GUI but I want to get the concept understood first as i'm still a new user to the software.

Thanks for all the help,

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/), using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to combine the row and column conditions (could also be done with `repmat`). Then use that index to apply the desired operation to the selected entries.

Let `A` denote your matrix:

```
ind = bsxfun(@and, A(1,:)>=5 & A(1,:)<=15, A(:,1)>=20 & A(:,1)<=41);
A(ind) = A(ind)*1.33;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create some kind of lookup function or data structure. I would create two vectors for your first row and first column separately from your "data" matrix, and use find() function to look up the corresponding index.

If you know the indices of the values that you want to modify in your matrix, then,

```
A(3:6,2:4) = 1.33*A(3:6,2:4);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would actually use 2 indices, one for each dimension.

I assume your data is in one matrix but it should not be too hard to adjust for the case where you use 2 vectrices and a matrix.

```
idx1 = A(1,:)>=5 & A(1,:)<=15;
idx2 = A(:,1)>=20 & A(:,1)<=41);

A(idx1,idx2) = A(idx1,idx2)*1.33
```